# Can't use method?

Tags: java, generics

I have an assignment to implement a generic Pair interface that represents ordered pairs like (x,y).  I'm trying to write the equals method, but I have to make the parameter a general object instead of a pair, so I don't know how to get the coordinates of it.  I get a symbol not found error when I try to compile because the Object class doesn't have a fst and snd method.  Should I be throwing an exception or something?  Note:  My professor gave us a template and I'm just filling in the methods, I don't think I'm allowed to change params or methods.

Here's relevant code:

```
    public class Pair<T1,T2> implements PairInterface<T1,T2>
{
private T1 x;
private T2 y;

public Pair(T1 aFirst, T2 aSecond)
{
    x = aFirst;
    y = aSecond;
}

/**
 * Gets the first element of this pair.
 * @return the first element of this pair.
 */
public T1 fst()
{
    return x;
}

/**
 * Gets the second element of this pair.
 * @return the second element of this pair.
 */
public T2 snd()
{
    return y;
}
```

...

```
    /**
 * Checks whether two pairs are equal. Note that the pair
 * (a,b) is equal to the pair (x,y) if and only if a is
 * equal to x and b is equal to y.
 * @return true if this pair is equal to aPair. Otherwise
 * return false.
 */
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    if(otherObject == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
    {
        return false;
    }
    T1 a = otherObject.fst();
    T2 b = otherObject.snd();
    if (x.equals(a) && y.equals(b))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
    ./Pair.java:66: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method fst()
    location: class java.lang.Object
    T1 a = otherObject.fst();
                      ^
    ./Pair.java:67: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method snd()
    location: class java.lang.Object
    T2 b = otherObject.snd();
                      ^
```

Comment: Read the section about casting in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html. Frankly, I'm surprised your teacher makes you use generics, which are a quite complex matter, if you don't know how to cast yet. Also, your code would be sooo much readable if you used `first`and `second` instead of `fst` and `snd`.

Comment: You will need to do the explicit casting once you established the actual object type.

Comment: You have to cast the other object to be a pair, first `Pair<?, ?> otherPair = (Pair<?, ?>)otherObject;`.

Answer (score 4):

The parameter to the `equals` method is an `Object`, which is not guaranteed to have your methods `fst` or `snd`, hence the compiler error.  To be able to call those methods, you need to have a `Pair` object.

It is standard practice to test the class of the object passed in, to see if it's even the same class as `this`, returning `false` if it's not the same class. Usually that is done with `instanceof`, followed by a cast if `true`.  The cast allows the compiler to treat the object as if it is the class that you say it is.  This allows the compiler to find the methods you want to call.

```
if(otherObject == null)
{
    return false;
}

// Use instanceof
if(!(otherObject instanceof Pair))
{
    return false;
}
// Cast - use <?, ?>; we don't know what they are.
Pair<?, ?> otherPair = (Pair<?, ?>) otherObject;
Object a = otherPair.fst();
Object b = otherPair.snd();
// Simplified return
return (x.equals(a) && y.equals(b));
```

Comment: I think you mean   !(otherObject instanceof Pair) return false ... ?

Comment: The difference with the `getClass()` method and this one is that this one allows subclasses. The statement "returning false if it's not the same class" is incorrect. Please note this.

Answer (score 0):

after class comparison `if(getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) return false;`

you need to create new variable with proper type, like this:

```
Pair<T1,T2> pair = (Pair<T1,T2>)otherObject;
```

then you will be able to use `pair` and its methods

Comment: Can you actually do `<T1,T2>` or are they supposed to use `<?, ?>`? I'm thinking about that at the moment, and I'm not sure.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you can use both, I prefer to cast to T1,T2

Answer (score 0):

Cast your otherObject to a Pair before calling its methods.

```
Pair<T1, T2> otherPair = (Pair) otherObject;
T1 a = otherPair.fst();
T2 b = otherPair.snd();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you do not cast otherObject first, so JVM think it was of type Object. An Object does not have methods fst() and snd(), so it fails.

To solve, cast otherObject to Pair then call fst() and snd():

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    if(otherObject == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
    {
        return false;
    }


    T1 a = ((Pair<T1, T2>)otherObject).fst();
    T2 b = ((Pair<T1, T2>)otherObject).snd();
    if (x.equals(a) && y.equals(b))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have ensured that `getClass() != otherObject.getClass()` is true, you may perform a *safe* cast to `Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) otherObject;`. Then, use your code as it is. **Note: You cannot perform a safe cast to `Pair<T1, T2>`, as you only know that otherObject is an instance of `Pair<?, ?>`. Your comparison with `.equals()` should still work, however.**

Comment: Note: you can perform safe cast to Pair<T1, T2> as during runtime they are actually just Object

Comment: @Lashane During runtime, it is actually `Pair`. And, although this cast is legal, it is bad practice. It might not be a `Pair<T1, T2>`, so calling it this is not a good idea.

Comment: actually casting to object is bad practice, especially if T is something like `T extends SomeInterface`

Comment: @Lashane what casting to object, and what `T`? I cannot understand what you are referring to.

Comment: `Pair<?,?>` means cast to `Pair<Object, Object>` so if `T` is declared as extends some interface - you will not be able to use this interface methods without additional casting

Comment: @Lashane in this case, all that is needed is a `Pair<?, ?>` to compare to. You don't actually need to use `T`, but you also don't know what it is, which is the perfect place to use a wildcard. It doesn't matter if `T` extends some interface, as none of its methods are used.

Comment: depends on your comparison logic, if you just use equals for all properties - `?`/`Object` is enough, for more complex cases (I mentioned one example above), you want to cast to T. Anyway my point was - emphasized part of your question is technically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the other object explicitly to be a pair, first (considering you already know it's a `Pair` object because the classes are the same), but you don't know what type it has, so you should use a wild card.

```
Pair<?, ?> otherPair = (Pair<?, ?>)otherObject;
//add null-checks if fst() or snd() is nullable
if(this.fst().equals(otherPair.fst()) && this.snd().equals(otherPair.snd()) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The construct `if (foo) return true; else return false;` may be simplified to `return foo;`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 yep, I just figured this is cleaner for a first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any object type to equals(), so part of properly implementing equals is to check the type of the argument Object.

If you look at the java core classes, they usually start by checking == and then whether it's an instanceof the class implementing equals().

Generally speaking, you should check:
1) == equality, ie, whether the argument is a reference to the current object itself- if it is, the objects should be equal per equals(). This is computationally cheap. 
2) whether the argument is null. This is also computationally cheap and if true, ensures that equals() returns false.
3) whether or not the argument object is an  instance of the current object's class. If it isn't it can't be equal and the cast will fail anyway. 
4) then cast it and start comparing the parts to one another

Lazy programmer tip- eclipse can automatically generate nice java equals() blocks using a wizard. It's in right click > source > generate hashcode() equals() and bam, it generates a proper equals() method.